# iMac and Macbook Pro

Tags: thunderbolt

I have a Panasonic DV camera which I cannot download via fire wire on the Camera and the USB on the iMac. (iMac doesn't pick up the camera). Apple recommend use of the thunderbolt port. I cannot trace a firewire to thunderbolt connector cable. Firewire to USB I have, and I am able to get a female USB connector. However, I cannot find a thunderbolt to USB to make this option possible. Anyone any suggestions please?

Comment: Sorry to here that you can't download your Panasonic DV camera via fire wire on the Camera—just what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You must have just missed it. Apple seems to sell a Thunderbolt to Firewire cable [here.](http://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MD464LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter) As always a bit pricy, but you could probably find other cheaper 3rd party ones.

Comment: Didn't miss it I've been into the shop. Apple can provide a Thunderbolt to Firewire adaptor but the firewire end is a female connection. I need male(tb)  to male firewire on opposite ends of the cable.